# Let $f:[0,\frac{\pi}{2}] \to \mathbb R$ is defined as $f(x):=\text{max}\left\{x^2,\cos(x)\right\}$ for all $x \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}] $

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,\frac{\pi}{2}] \to \mathbb R$ is defined as $f(x):=\text{max}\left\{x^2,\cos(x)\right\}$ for all $x \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}] $,show that an absolute minimum $x_0 \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ for $f$ on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ and $x_0$ is the solution to the equation $\cos(x)=x^2$.

---

Let $x_0$ be the point where the two functions intersect,on $[0,x_0]$ we have that $\cos(x) \ge x^2$ and on $[x_0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ we have that $x^2 \ge \cos(x)$,from here we see that $$f(x)=\color{blue}{\cos(x)\ge \cos(x_0)}=f(x_0) \tag{$x \in [0,x_0]$}$$
$$f(x)=x^2 \ge x_0^2=f(x_0) \tag{$x \in [x_0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$}$$

So for all $x \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ we see that $f(x) \ge f(x_0)$ and this implies $x_0$ is an absolute minimum of $f$ over $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$,moreover we know that $x_0$ is the solution to the given equation .

I have two questions,how without using the concept of derivative we are able to show that the blue part does hold?

And how do we know that "on $[0,x_0]$ we have that $\cos(x) \ge x^2$ and on $[x_0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ we have that $x^2 \ge \cos(x)$"?

Comment: Note, $\cos x$ is strictly decreasing and $x^2$ is strictly increasing on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ and at $x=0,$ we have, $cos 0=1> 0$ , hence result follows.

Comment: Plot the graph of $ x^2$ and $cosx$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

The blue inequality immediately follows from the fact that $\cos x$ is decreasing on $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Also the map $g(x) = \cos x - x^2$ is the difference of a decreasing map and an increasing map on $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$. Therefore it is decreasing on that interval. The fact that $g(0)=1$ and $g(\pi/2) = -\pi^2/4$ provides the answer to your second question.

Comment: What do you mean? $g$ is the sum of $\cos x$ and $-x^2$ which are both decreasing. Hence it is decreasing.